How to create text with "arrow background"
I'm trying to achieve the following effect:

I have many of these to add to a text, so doing this manually is not practical. What would be the preferred way of achieving this ? I've already created all the variations of this that I need, but adding these images manually in all the places I need is going to be a huge pain (I'm using indesign for my text layout)
I've thought about creating a custom font: being able to simply write this as "[Continent>Country>City]" would be awesome, but I'm not sure how to do that. I'd like to retain the ability to update the colors, but I can do without
Is there a "standard way" of doing this ?

The only way I can think to accomplish this is manually, with inline objects. I don't think any formatting is going to accomplish the color variations and the curved/pointed caps.

The exact design shown in your original post is especially complicated because the shapes overlap. I'll assume the main requirements for your work are rather that:

the text in the colored boxes can be edited while the box automatically changes its width;
the boxes can themselve be easily inserted in the main text, and move inside it when it is modified.

Here's a construction which fulfills these conditions. On top of the picture, there are the three individual shapes, and below them is an example of main text with the shapes inserted in it. The vertical alignement is not perfect, but this could be mitigated with smaller boxes:

[Construction]
The main ingredients to reproduce this are:

Creating rectangles with a small height and the desired fill colors. In the Properties pannel, change their corners to reproduce the pattern shown in the picture.
Type some text inside the rectangle with the text tool (T) being active.
Open the text object properties (Ctrl + B when the rectangle is selected). In the General pannel, select Align: Centre so that the text is justified, and choose the Inset spacing values that you like. In the Auto-size pannel, select Auto-sizing: Width Only so that the rectangle extends when more text is added in it.
One by one, copy each box and past it in the main text.

This construction can be repeated throughout the whole text by copying and pasting the boxes where needed. Additionally, you could create 3 Object styles (Window > Styles > Object styles) that apply to a rectangle the desired corner effects, the height, the fill color and so on, so that any rectangle can be turned into one of these boxes in one clock.
[Remaining fixes]
This solution is not perfect: I tried to fix the vertical alignement of the boxes using the Baseline shift property from the Paragraph pannel, but this seems to only shift the text inside the box. I also tried to reproduce your exact design using a right bevel on each box, followed by a space character with negative Tracking from the Character pannel, but the left box appears behind the box on the right which hides the arrow-shaped bevel. Still, I hope this will help you to solve your problem!

Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, your proposal did not work for me: the flat edges between the words and the spacing don't match the design I was going for. I ended up creating each individual option in figma, exporting them all as images, importing them in indesign, and spent a few hours copy / pasting.
Again, thank you for your help, and sorry for not going with your solution

No worry haha, plus answering is never a loss of time on this forum since it helps to (re)discover some functionalities and find intelligent ways to use them :)
